# Scrapy loops until fail when changing proxy outside of the program

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy

I have a program to change the ip address of the computer, which runs fine.
I have tried crawling my scrapy project on each server ip address and it works fine.

However sometimes when the program swaps the ip address while the program is running scrapy gives the error:

```
2019-07-19 14:35:38 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Proxy is detected https://127.0.0.1:21218
2019-07-19 14:35:38 [scrapy_user_agents.middlewares] DEBUG: Assigned User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/5
37.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36
2019-07-19 14:35:38 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Retrying <GET http://www.ebay.com/sch/allcategories/all-categories
/?_rdc=1> (failed 175 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl3_get_record', 'wrong vers
ion number')]>]
```

Sometimes my IP address will change and it will continue but sometimes it will fail and will loop spitting this code out, retrying 200 times.

Comment: Alright, but what's the question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a redirect which was breaking it, so I added

```
meta = {'dont_redirect': True, 'handle_httpstatus_list': [301,302]}
```

to my yield and it works fine